# Android - Logcat is not logging my messages

Tags: android, eclipse, logging, logcat, android-logcat

Sometimes i get the problem that LogCat is not logging my messages. Yesterday i got this problem again and I still could not fix it. In generally LogCat is logging and i can also click on the logs for my specific apps. I see some logs but i cant find my own logs.
I searched for my special "test" tag and for the text, but i guess logcat dont want to log my things. My app is running and i get no exceptions or anything (or I may just cant see them...).

A little part of my main activity where i try to log stuff.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.e("test", "LOG MY MESSAGE!!!!");

        List<Group> groups = null;enter code here


        GroupScraperTask task = new GroupScraperTask();
        try {   
            groups = task.execute("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H").get();    
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "Main Activity " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you see logs from other application?

Comment: Try restarting Eclipse - that usually fixes it whenever I have this problem.

Comment: @NickolaiAstashonok I created a new project to test that and i can see my logs there. But i dont know how to find out whats the problem with my other application.

Comment: @camdroid Logging works with other Applications

Comment: Oh i fixed it, i realised that eclipse did not use my freshest application when i run it from my run configuration. The problem was that my application was marked as a library (rightclick -> properties -> android). I'm not sure why eclipse didnt tell me that there was a problem but now its working again! :)